Rust downcasting a dyn trait to a concrete struct does not work
Assuming that have an element Sparrow that implements the trait Bird, I now want to cast the trait object to the bird.
Reading other answers on SO, i assumed to be able to cast it to Any and then continue with the downcast_ref option.
Unfortunately, this does not seem to work in my case
let bird: Rc<RefCell<dyn Bird>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Sparrow{ }));
let any_bird: &dyn Any = &bird;
let sparrow_option = any_bird.downcast_ref::<Sparrow>();
if sparrow_option.is_some() {
    println!("TAG OK");
} else {
    println!("TAG ERROR");
}

What can i do to actually cast the trait content of Rc<RefCell<dyn Bird>> to Sparrow?

The concrete type behind any_bird is Rc<RefCell<dyn Bird>>, not Sparrow, so .downcast_ref() will only succeed with that type. Rc<RefCell<Sparrow>> will not work either.
To get a reference to the inner Sparrow, you'd need to use the as_any trick on your Bird trait described here: How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object? And then it would look something like this:
if let Some(sparrow) = bird.borrow().as_any().downcast_ref::<Sparrow>() {
    println!("its a sparrow!");
} else {
    println!("its something else");
}

